# Hiding Unselected div dl dt, instead of a table content with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

What if I wanted to use this same solution on a different structure, such as a dl dt module instead of a table?
How would I structure the JQuery code to display the label of the selected product?

I have tried multiple methods to display the nearest label to no avail.

Please see the Code Snippet to demonstrate.

```
<div class="attributes">
    <dl>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_390"><label class="text-prompt"> CANVAS PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_390">
            <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1"><select name="product_attribute_390"
                    id="product_attribute_390">
                    <option value="0">---</option>
                    <option value="2391">8" X 12" [+$26.00]</option>
                    <option value="2392">10" X 12" [+$28.00]</option>
                    <option value="2393">16" X 20" [+$35.00]</option>
                    <option value="2394">20" X 24" [+$60.00]</option>
                    <option value="2395">24" X 36" [+$50.00]</option>
                    <option value="2396">30" X 40" [+$66.00]</option>
                    <option value="2397">36" X 48" [+$142.00]</option>
                    <option value="2398">40" X 60" [+$200.00]</option>
                </select>
                <span class="select-box">
                    <span class="select-inner">---</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_386"><label class="text-prompt"> ACRYLIC PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_386">
            <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1"><select name="product_attribute_386"
                    id="product_attribute_386">
                    <option value="0">---</option>
                    <option value="2361">8" x 12" [+$70.00]</option>
                    <option value="2362">12" X 16" [+$80.00]</option>
                    <option value="2363">12" X 36" [+$160.00]</option>
                    <option value="2364">16" x 20" [+$110.00]</option>
                    <option value="2365">20" x 24" [+$208.00]</option>
                    <option value="2366">20" x 30" [+$220.00]</option>
                    <option value="2367">30" x 40" [+$280.00]</option>
                </select>
                <span class="select-box">
                    <span class="select-inner">---</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_387"><label class="text-prompt"> METAL PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_387">
            <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1"><select name="product_attribute_387"
                    id="product_attribute_387">
                    <option value="0">---</option>
                    <option value="2368">8" x 12" [+$60.00]</option>
                    <option value="2369">12" x 16" [+$70.00]</option>
                    <option value="2370">12" x 36" [+$252.00]</option>
                    <option value="2371">16" x 20" [+$80.00]</option>
                    <option value="2372">20" x 24" [+$160.00]</option>
                    <option value="2373">20" x 30" [+$220.00]</option>
                    <option value="2374">30" x 40" [+$356.00]</option>
                </select>
                <span class="select-box">
                    <span class="select-inner">---</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I tried using JQuery to hide the unselected labels and could not find a way to selectively display the active select.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").each(function () {
        $(this).on("change", function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            //alert(val);
            console.log(val);
            if (val > 0) {
                $('.add-to-cart').show();
                $('.attribute-description').hide();
                $("select").hide();
                $('.text-prompt').hide();
                $(this).show();
                $(this).closest('.text-prompt').show();
                $(this).closest('label').find('.text-prompt').show();
                $(this).closest('dt label .text-prompt').show();

            } else {
                $("select").show();
                $('.select-wrap').show();
                $('.attribute-description').show();
                $('.add-to-cart').hide();
                $('.text-prompt').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="attributes">
    <dl>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_390">
            <label class="text-prompt"> CANVAS PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_390">
            <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1">
                <select name="product_attribute_390"
                    id="product_attribute_390">
                    <option value="0">---</option>
                    <option value="2391">8" X 12" [+$26.00]</option>
                    <option value="2392">10" X 12" [+$28.00]</option>
                    <option value="2393">16" X 20" [+$35.00]</option>
                    <option value="2394">20" X 24" [+$60.00]</option>
                    <option value="2395">24" X 36" [+$50.00]</option>
                    <option value="2396">30" X 40" [+$66.00]</option>
                    <option value="2397">36" X 48" [+$142.00]</option>
                    <option value="2398">40" X 60" [+$200.00]</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </dd>
        <p>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_386">
            <label class="text-prompt"> ACRYLIC PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_386">
            <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1">
                <select name="product_attribute_386"
                    id="product_attribute_386">
                    <option value="0">---</option>
                    <option value="2361">8" x 12" [+$70.00]</option>
                    <option value="2362">12" X 16" [+$80.00]</option>
                    <option value="2363">12" X 36" [+$160.00]</option>
                    <option value="2364">16" x 20" [+$110.00]</option>
                    <option value="2365">20" x 24" [+$208.00]</option>
                    <option value="2366">20" x 30" [+$220.00]</option>
                    <option value="2367">30" x 40" [+$280.00]</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </dd>
        <p>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_387">
            <label class="text-prompt"> METAL PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_387">
            <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1">
                <select name="product_attribute_387" id="product_attribute_387">
                    <option value="0">---</option>
                    <option value="2368">8" x 12" [+$60.00]</option>
                    <option value="2369">12" x 16" [+$70.00]</option>
                    <option value="2370">12" x 36" [+$252.00]</option>
                    <option value="2371">16" x 20" [+$80.00]</option>
                    <option value="2372">20" x 24" [+$160.00]</option>
                    <option value="2373">20" x 30" [+$220.00]</option>
                    <option value="2374">30" x 40" [+$356.00]</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the value of select is not `0` depending on this show your label using `$(this).closest("dd").prev().find(".text-prompt")` else show your div using `$(".attribute-description").show()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != '0') {
      $("dd").not($(this).closest("dd")).hide() //hide other
      $("dt").not($(this).closest("dd").prev()).hide()
      //show label
      $(this).closest("dd").prev().find(".text-prompt").show()
      $(this).closest("dd").prev().find(".attribute-description").hide()
    } else {
      $("dd ,dt").show()
      $(".attribute-description").show()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="attributes">
  <dl>
    <dt id="product_attribute_label_390">
            <label class="text-prompt"> CANVAS PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
    <dd id="product_attribute_input_390">
      <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1">
        <select name="product_attribute_390" id="product_attribute_390">
          <option value="0">---</option>
          <option value="2391">8" X 12" [+$26.00]</option>
          <option value="2392">10" X 12" [+$28.00]</option>
          <option value="2393">16" X 20" [+$35.00]</option>
          <option value="2394">20" X 24" [+$60.00]</option>
          <option value="2395">24" X 36" [+$50.00]</option>
          <option value="2396">30" X 40" [+$66.00]</option>
          <option value="2397">36" X 48" [+$142.00]</option>
          <option value="2398">40" X 60" [+$200.00]</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </dd>
    <p>
      <dt id="product_attribute_label_386">
            <label class="text-prompt"> ACRYLIC PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
      <dd id="product_attribute_input_386">
        <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1">
          <select name="product_attribute_386" id="product_attribute_386">
            <option value="0">---</option>
            <option value="2361">8" x 12" [+$70.00]</option>
            <option value="2362">12" X 16" [+$80.00]</option>
            <option value="2363">12" X 36" [+$160.00]</option>
            <option value="2364">16" x 20" [+$110.00]</option>
            <option value="2365">20" x 24" [+$208.00]</option>
            <option value="2366">20" x 30" [+$220.00]</option>
            <option value="2367">30" x 40" [+$280.00]</option>
          </select>

        </div>
      </dd>
      <p>
        <dt id="product_attribute_label_387">
            <label class="text-prompt"> METAL PRINTS </label>
            <div class="attribute-description">
                <p>Please Choose your Size:</p>
            </div>
        </dt>
        <dd id="product_attribute_input_387">
          <div class="select-wrap" data-children-count="1">
            <select name="product_attribute_387" id="product_attribute_387">
              <option value="0">---</option>
              <option value="2368">8" x 12" [+$60.00]</option>
              <option value="2369">12" x 16" [+$70.00]</option>
              <option value="2370">12" x 36" [+$252.00]</option>
              <option value="2371">16" x 20" [+$80.00]</option>
              <option value="2372">20" x 24" [+$160.00]</option>
              <option value="2373">20" x 30" [+$220.00]</option>
              <option value="2374">30" x 40" [+$356.00]</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </dd>
  </dl>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```